# Should redundant "also" with "too" in the same sentence count as a (style) error?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, errors

As a non-native English speaker, I keep seeing (professional) articles, often by native speakers of English, that say something like "The bass is also quite strong too". This strikes me as wrong due to the clumsy-looking redundancy of using both "also" and "too" at the same time.

Would I be correct in considering this either bad style at best or a grammar error at worst? (And which of those would it be?)

Comment: Can you provide specific examples. It's impossible to judge someone's style without understanding what they are trying to say or do. A pedant might object to redundancy in eg *Alexander and the Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad Day*, but so what?

Comment: As stylistic flaws go, that's piddling.

Comment: @StuartF That's an example of redundancy for emphasis, like saying "teeny little" or "great big". The redundancy in the OP's quote just seems like a mistake.

Comment: 'A grammar error at worst' elevates (or the reverse) grammar errors to the worst of misdemeanours. But Orwell includes _Break any of the other laws [he lists] rather than say something sounding outlandish_. And Grice lists essentials of reasonable conversation including clarity, relevance, conciseness and truthfulness/accuracy of fact. That said, as Barmar says, redundancy can be useful for emphasis –  and is idiomatic in certain phrases (spic and span; rant and rave; leaps and bounds ...).

Comment: @StuartF "It just seems like a mistake"... I was making the point that I see this *very often* in exactly the same way it is shown in the example. So I wanted to get an idea of the "correctness" of my gut-feeling flagging this as "bad style" that appears to have become mainstream already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with it, just as there's no incorrect grammar in saying

> I went to the store and I went to the store.

It's simply redundant and unnecessary. Errors like this are common in speech, since you don't always remember that you already expressed the concept earlier in the sentence (problems like this tend to occur more on long sentences). But if I were an English teacher grading a writing assignment I'd probably take off for this error.

Redundancy can sometimes be useful for emphasis, but it doesn't seem like there's a need to emphasize anything in your example.

Comment: Thanks, so in other words (in the given context) "bad style" and definitely something professional bloggers etc. shouldn't do if they want to write quality content.

Comment: Yes. My general experience since the rise of Internet-based publishing has been that writing quality has declined. Newspapers and magazines used to have proofreaders who would catch mistakes like these, but even professional bloggers often work alone. So sloppy writing gets through.